# Телефон и карта

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *номер телефона привязан к банковской карте* или *карта привязана к номеру телефона*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Карта первична, поэтому номер телефона привязан к ней, а не наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думал, но не был уверен.)

Comment: В большинстве случаев это так, но возможна ситуация, в которой можно иначе отнестись к тому, что чему подчинено: например, отдельная карта заведена специально для обслуживания телефонных расходов, и на ней подключён автоплатёж.

Comment: Мне кажется, это вопрос из серии "что первично - курица или яйцо?". Карта и телефон взаимопривязаны, оба выражения верны: и карту можно привязать к телефону, и телефон к карте."В аккаунте Сбербанк Онлайн пользователи могут узнать, к какому номеру привязана карта Сбербанка"http://sbankin.com/mobilnyi-bank/perevod-na-kartu-sberbanka.html

"Если у получателя имеется несколько карт Сбербанка, привязанных к одному номеру телефона, оптимальная карта для зачисления определяется автоматически" - это с сайтов банка.